# Assign each row to every other row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
**Table user**
Username

**Table prize**
PrizeName
```

How can you assign for each prize,  rows in **table prize** to each username I have in **table user**?

For example:

```
**Username**
Bob
Alice

**table prize**
Iphone5
Iphone6
```

Result:

```
**Username**    **prize**
Bob             iphone5
Alice           iphone5
Bob             iphone6
Alice           iphone6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CROSS JOIN. CROSS JOIN will return all of the results in a result set. Using your example:

SELECT
 Name, p.PrizeName
FROM
 dbo.[User]
CROSS JOIN Prize p

This returns:

Bob iphone 5
Alice   iphone 5
Bob iphone 6
Alice   iphone 6

[A Screen Capture of the result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POZpF.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Cartesian Product. Use a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM UserTable UT
     CROSS JOIN PrizeTable PT;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the following should get you what you want:

```
SELECT Username, Prize
FROM 
user
CROSS JOIN
prize
ORDER BY prize, Username
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select u.username, p.prize
from users u cross join
     prizes p;
```

I name tables in the plural, because they contain multiple instances of entities (and plurals are less likely to conflict with keywords).

If you want to "assign" them, then you may want a junction table.  For this, you would normally have ids and do something like this:

```
insert into user_prizes (user_id, prize_id)
    select u.user_id, p.prize_id
    from users u cross join
         prizes p;
```

Comment: `USER` is a reserved keyword in T-SQL. You'd need to quote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_User_Prizes
           (Username, PrizeName)
SELECT Table_User.Username,table_Prize.PrizeName
FROM Table_User,table_Prize
```

Note that if the "table_User_Prizes" has more columns, they will be filled as NULL.

Comment: Time to stop using ANSI-89 style joins in favor of ANSI-92 style joins. It has been over 25 years now. And if you want a cross join, then use an explicit cross join. And this already has four other identical answers.